# Return data from function

Tags: javascript, function

How can I return the data (csvData) from the reader.onload function. I want that the data will return from readCsv function:

```
 async readCSV(event) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
    var csvToJson;
    csvToJson = reader.onload = async () => {
      const text = reader.result;
      const csvData =  await this.csvJSON(text);
      return csvData;
    };
    return csvToJson;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you already using `async` syntax. Async syntax automatically wraps everything to [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instance.

But you also can return [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instance manually. It accepts callback with `resolve` & `reject` arguments. And you can call `resolve` to resolve the promise.

```js
async function readCSV(event) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
        reader.onload = async () => {
            const text = reader.result;
            const csvData =  await this.csvJSON(text);
            resolve(csvData);
        };
    });
}
```