# Is there a way to use async/await with this algolia example code?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, algolia

This code i am about to put here does not work in the respect that my graphQL server always receives an empty array back... i know this is because the call completes before the data is available.. i don't have much experience with promises so i am wondering how i can get it to work, i played with a bunch of different combinations to attempt to await the response so that i could just pass back an array of id's to the playground... the browsewr.on(end) part works fine and the proper data shows in the console? Anyone care to shed some light for me?

```
  const browser = await lookbookIndex.browseAll();
  let hits = [];
  let returnArray = [];

  browser.on('result', (content) => {
    hits = hits.concat(content.hits);
  });

  browser.on('end', () => {
    console.log('Finished!');
    console.log('We got %d hits', hits.length);
    returnArray = hits ? hits.map(a => a.objectID) : [];
  });

  browser.on('error', err => err);

  return returnArray;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async syntax automatically wraps everything to [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instance.

But you also can return [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instance manually. It accepts callback with `resolve` & `reject` arguments. And you can call `resolve` to resolve the promise:

```js
async function search() {
    const browser = await lookbookIndex.browseAll();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let hits = [];

        browser.on('result', (content) => {
            hits = hits.concat(content.hits);
        });

        browser.on('end', () => {
            console.log('Finished!');
            console.log('We got %d hits', hits.length);
            resolve(hits ? hits.map(a => a.objectID) : [])
        });

        browser.on('error', err => reject(err));
    })
}
```

And you can `await` the promise:

```js
await new Promise(...)
```

Similar questions:

- [Return data from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64587264/return-data-from-function/64587336#64587336)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this was blocking me from accomplishing a bigger task and works great... i really appreciate it..

Comment: If you use the promise constructor you can drop the async keyword.

Comment: Technically yes, but if you are using linting (eslint, tslint), it may require all functions which return promise to be async.

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)! Put the `await lookbookIndex.browseAll();` outside of the callback

Comment: Good point, I didn't notice that `browseAll` was an async function.